# MySql query (joins)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table "item" with columns::

```
|id(primary_key)|parent_id|name|
```

I need to get all items that not have children.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT [some cols]
  FROM item i
       LEFT JOIN item children ON children.parent_id = i.id
 WHERE children.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Correct answer. If parent_id is indexed, it will be efficient.

Comment: Can you provide some education around your `JOIN` condition and `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @Jason, sure: This is technique is called a self-exclusion join. You are adding more information to the resultset, and then eliminating from the final resultset everything you do not want. Here is a good explanation of an exclusion join: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/09/23/how-to-write-a-sql-exclusion-join/ and once you've read that you can see a slightly more complex example here: http://adam-bernier.appspot.com/post/38001/the-self-exclusion-join

Comment: Thanks, @Jason. I upvoted your answer because it works, and is helpful.

Comment: its not working 1. children.id IS NULL should be children.parent_id 2. other bug that I cant find

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM item WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT parent_id FROM item)
```

There are other ways to write this query that may be more performant. But this should get you started.

It will select all records with an `id` that is not found in the `parent_id` column - meaning this record does not have children.

Comment: Can you please give solution with use of join?

Comment: Sure thing. I would suggest you to specify these requirements in your original post.

Comment: This will make an unnecessary temp table.

Comment: @fsb, as I said in my answer - this is not the most performant way. However, to some user's it may be a more intuitive approach.

Comment: I agree that this is a much more intuitive way of solving the problem. It is a shame that MySQL has traditionally not supported subqueries as well as could be hoped. (Maybe that has changed in recent years; I do not use MySQL enough to know.)

Comment: @bob, **Adam Bernier** has provided your answer.